# qtranslate quick tags don't work in custom fields

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

Anyone familiar with qtranslate? Do you know how to enable custom field quick tag support? at the moment it just prints out `<!--:ge-->სახელი<!--:--><!--:en-->name<!--:--><!--:ru-->imia<!--:-->` without actually translating anything.

Answer (score 4):

I figured this one out too, 1-2 hours of research!

So, to make qtranslate quick tags work with custom fields, this is what you do:

```
<?php _e(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Activities', true));?>
```

_e and all quicktags work perfectly but not full version but shorthand version [:en] etc.